# Ruby on Rails Thumbs_up Redirect to User Sign In

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, voting

I'm getting this error when a user tries to vote without first being signed-in:

> undefined method `vote_for' for nil:NilClass

I have a regular "Post" scaffold and the users are voting on posts. How do I insert a command that redirects them to the user_sign_in if they're not already logged in?

```
class PostsController < InheritedResources::Base
  def vote_up
  begin
  current_user.vote_for(@post = Post.find(params[:id]))
  redirect_to [@post]
  flash[:success] = "You have voted successfully"
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
  redirect_to [@post]
  flash[:error] =  "You have already voted"
  end
 end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `before_filter :authenticate_user!` in your `PostController`.  In the `authenticate_user!` method check the user session, and if the user is not signed in redirect to `sign_in` path.

Edit: As you already have Devise adding the `before_filter` should take care of the redirection to sign in path if the user is not signed in.  The following will only work for `vote_up` action, if you'd like the same behavior for all the actions then you can replace the line with `before_filter :authenticate_user!`

```
class PostsController < InheritedResources::Base 
  # Add before_filter here and devise should handle the redirection if the user is not signed in.
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:vote_up]

  def vote_up
  begin
  current_user.vote_for(@post = Post.find(params[:id]))
  redirect_to [@post]
  flash[:success] = "You have voted successfully"
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
  redirect_to [@post]
  flash[:error] =  "You have already voted"
  end
 end

end
```

Comment: I've updated my post with the posts controller, can you show me an example of show to do that exactly?

Comment: Do you have authentication in place?  How are you authenticating users?

Comment: Devise... And Omniauth... and a couple of other things. But yes: I have authenticate_user! in place.

Comment: Please see my edit above.  I'm assuming that should take care of your users redirection if they are not logged in for the `vote_up` action.

Comment: Please edit your answer (for others of course :) ) You've written "before_filter:" and it should be "before_filter". But other than that THANKS! It works! :D